# How to disable file filtering in VS Code Sidebar / Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Visual Studio Code v1.32.3 on Mac OS, and for at least a few versions before this, I am often unable to create files and folders in the sidebar via the default key mappings of `a` and `shift+a`, and instead am greeted with a file search / filter.

[image]

> Typing "a" brings up this filter instead of launching the create file input under the selected folder

Restarting Code restores the file and folder creation behavior for some time, then seemingly out of nowhere the filter behavior takes over again, so I imagine there must be some other key shortcut I'm hitting that toggles the filter behavior.

I don't see any mappings in the default key bindings for those keys that suggest the search / filter behavior is intended:

```
{ "key": "a", 
  "command": "explorer.newFile",                                     
  "when": "filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+a", 
  "command": "explorer.newFolder",
  "when": "filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus" },
```

I've tried searching the preferences for "Explorer", "Side Bar", and "Filter" but can't find any reference to this filter feature.

So finally my question, how can I restore the file and folder creation behavior or completely disable this filtering behavior? I'm quite happy with `cmd+p` for finding files.

Or is this a bug? Happy to post issue on GitHub if so.

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Comment: I have not solved this issue. Right now it is not happening to me, perhaps because of new version, however I've made a note to myself to open an issue on GitHub if I experience it again and will post the link here

Comment: I asked at vscode repo and answered below :)

Comment: Most f***** annoying thing ever it takes over my keyboard whenever making new files grrrr

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of 2022, the older answers don't work. The easiest solution is to update the keybindings.
Here is how:

1. Open the `keybindings.json` from keyboard shortcuts settings. (⌘K + ⌘S)
   [image]
2. Remove the existing setting for `listSupportFind`. (When you search for `listSupportFind`, there are two settings. Please delete the cmd + f one) This is how it looks now:
   [image]

Thanks to @TrainedMusician for the answer above. Hope the description helps you fix it quickly.

Comment: For good measure keyboard shortcuts for creating a new file or new folder while in the sidebar still need to be added manually.

Comment: ehenrik answer was useful for me to reconfigure the keyboard shortcuts for cmd-F.

Answer (score 32):

as of vscode 1.33.1 the option is a bool
`"workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": false`

EDIT: this setting has been deprecated, see discussion below for possible solutions. Will update when resolved.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted. This is the correct answer as of June 8th 2019.

Comment: Oops, I think I down-voted by mistake. Just upvoted and marked as accepted answer.

Comment: For VScode 1.36.1 this answer is still correct.

Comment: If you go to settings and paste `workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation` into the search bar, the setting should pop up and you can set it to what you want.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be correct anymore in 2022, there is no such setting.

Comment: That's right, doesn't work in 2022.

Comment: yeah I can confirm this is no longer working

Answer (score 4):

Thomazella's answer isn't working anymore in 2022. [bradonomics](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67988#issuecomment-1242976726) mentions modifying the keybinding. There probably are two matches if you search for 'listSupportFind', I deleted the cmd + f one and it's all good now

[Here is a screenshot of keybindings after deleting one of the two shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LozcG.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: @DavidSchumann I tried that and it didn't seem to do anything. Pressing a or shift+a is not making a new file. I deleted all keybindings as suggested. I think it's because those bindings were for F3 presses, maybe unrelated? see github link. Not sure how to fix myself ATM.

Comment: @Thom what do you mean? a or shift + a are no known shortcuts or am I missing something?
On Mac simply hit [CMD + K + (CMD) S] and then search for the listSupportFind bindings, and delete the one you don't want

Comment: @TrainedMusician 's recommendation worked for me

Comment: Finally, got rid of this annoying feature. 
Thank you so much.

This works as of 1st March 2023.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD** see Thomazella's answer

**Old**
use this setting **"workbench.list.keyboardNavigation": "simple"**
and then reload window

[source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67988#issuecomment-491917551)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to disable this and I did it by changing the `When` statement for the shortcut command `list.find` for the shortcut `[cmd+ F]` to be `listFocus && listSupportsFind && !explorerViewletFocus`

Old value:

[image: Old value]

New value:

[image: New value]

Comment: two same screens

Comment: Indeed.  The screenshot only shows the New Value, which is the more important one. I'll edit the answer for clarity.